# Is it possible to execute a SpecFlow test run programmatically?

Tags: specflow

I would like to invoke SpecFlow tests programmatically. At runtime, I would like to start SpecRunner at some point in time, and execute the tests under the same (current) AppDomain.

Is there a class under TechTalk.SpecRun that can help me?

I have tried using TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner() but this class does not seem to actually kick off the tests.

EDIT: I am using SpecFlow 3, .NET 4.5.2

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Which part of the [documentation](https://specflow.org/documentation/Executing-SpecFlow-Tests/) is not clear?

Comment: Hi there, that documentation provides information to execute tests in a separate AppDomain, I would like the ability to execute tests in the _current_ AppDomain of the running application. Can I invoke SpecRunner dynamically/programmatically?